# error: "OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension" requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile in the Signing & Capabilities editor

Tags: react-native, onesignal, visual-studio-app-center

i use one signal to build push notifications in my app and every thing work right in debug and archive when make that from my xcode

when upload this version  on appcenter get error
##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65 while build
when try with other branch to build that on git build success

versions of library
React-native : 0.63.3

react-native-onesignal : 3.8.1

appcenter: 4.0.0

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP1Xz.png